# Hide the displayed part of a linked page when hovering over the link in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, preview, hyperlink

I'm using the `hyperref` package and when I hover over an entry in the table of contents (which points to a section) I get a glimpse of the beginning of that section. I've searched some options in the `hyperref` manual, but none seem to disable this pop-up.

Is this caused by the package itself or by something else? Just to make sure I'm clear on this I uploaded an image example below.

[image: Example of the problem]

This might also be a feature of the pdf document viewer that I'm using, if not I hope you can give me a hint on how to disable this.

EDIT:
Here's the most simple code:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin {document}
    \tableofcontents
    \pagebreak
   \section{First Section}
   \hrule
   \pagebreak
   \section{Second Section}
   \hrule    
\end{document}
```

The document viewer I'm using is called [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince).

Comment: Without seeing the document's code and knowing the kind of PDF viewer you are using it is impossible to help. Please provide a minimal compilable code example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, made an edit to my original post! :)

Comment: Interesting feature. Seems to be viewer-related. I am using evince-3.36 here (not the most recent release, but from 7/2020); it doesn't behave like this.

Comment: BTW, you are using an unusual font encoding. If you have English text, use `[T1]`.

Comment: I was using cyrillic letters so I just copied over the encoding.And yeah it might be Evince, my version is for Gnome 3.38.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is an Evince specific feature, you can see [original issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/662).

Comment: Someone requested an option to be added that allows the preview to be disabled and the discussion can be seen here https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1521.

Although there seems to be a lot of push-back in the discussion.